# dojo tabbed container question

Tags: javascript, dojo, tabcontainer

I have a TabContainer with 3 tabs which I create using the declarative way.  The total number of tabs are 6 for the container, however the last 3 are added programmatically because of the size of the data, server calls, etc.  What I need is for the page to fully load, then make the ajax call to get the data and create the other tabs. I added the code for this in the addOnLoad method, however the ajax call is being made before the page loads.  How can I made the ajax call right after the page is loaded.  Thank you guys in advance, your response is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to ensure your javascript code executes after the page is loaded is to use

```
dojo.ready(function(){
//talk to server
//create new tabs
});
```